What is $\min\{ m+k\}$ such that $ \binom{m}{k}=n$?
Now asked on here.

Most numbers in pascal triangle appear only once ( excluding the duplicates in the same row of the Pascal's triangle)  but  certain numbers appear multiple times. For instance, 6 appears twice as $\binom{4}{2}$ and $\binom{6}{1}$. Here I asked my self What is $\min\{ m+k\}$ such that $ \binom{m}{k}=n$?

Define the sequence $a_n$ as follows: $a_n = \min\{m + k\}$ such that $\binom{m}{k}=n.$
The initial terms of $a_n$ (arranged in $(n,a_n)$) are:

( 2, 3),
( 3, 4),
( 4, 5),
( 5, 6),
( 6, 6),
( 7, 8),
( 8, 9),
( 9, 10),
( 10, 7),
( 11, 12),
( 12, 13),
( 13, 14),
( 14, 15),
( 15, 8),
( 16, 17),
( 17, 18),
( 18, 19),
( 19, 20),
( 20, 9),
( 21, 9),
( 22, 23),
( 23, 24),
( 24, 25),
( 25, 26),
( 26, 27),
( 27, 28),
( 28, 10),
( 29, 30),
( 30, 31),
( 31, 32),
( 32, 33),
( 33, 34),
( 34, 35),
( 35, 10)

(The bold numbers are which has $a_n< n+1$)
These are generated by this code:
import math
print("the input is the maximum number $n$ to check for i.e for all j between 1, n the code gives the min{m+k} such that mCk =n , the output is in the for of $(n , min (m+k : mCk=n)) $")
j=int(input())
for n in range (2,j+1):
    C=[]

    l=0
    for m in range (1, n+1):
        s=0


        k=1
        while k<( math.floor(m/2)+1-l):
            if math.comb(m,k)>n:
                l=l+1
                break
            if math.comb(m,k)==n:
                C.insert(s,m+k )
                s=s+1
                if min(C)<n+1:

                    break
            k=k+1                      
    print(f"({n},{min(C)}), ")                               

Here are some graphs of $(n,a_n)$:




It is easy to see that:
Most n have $a_n =n+1$, The  numbers $n$ with $a_n < n+1$ are of the form $\binom{r}{q}$ where $2 \le  q \le r-2$.
These numbers are precisely the ones that appear more than once in Pascal's triangle (excluding symmetric pairs in the same row of Pascal's triangle ).
The question is: How to find $a_n$ where $n$ has the form $\binom{r}{q}$ where $2 \le  q \le r-2$?

It seems that for such $n$, the minimum $m + k$ occurs when $m$ is minimized (the first occurrence of $n$ in Pascal's triangle) This is true up to  $n=50,000,000,000,000$ . Can this be proven?


Here are the first few $a_n$ where $n$ has the form $\binom{r}{q}$ where $2 \le  q \le r-2$:

6,
7,
8,
9,
9,
10,
10,
11,
12,
13,
11,
14,
12,
15,
12,
16,
17,
13,
13,
19,
20,
14,
21,
22,
14,
15,
24,
15,
25,
26,
16,
27,
28,
15,
29,
17,
30,
31,
32,
18,
16,
33,
16,
34,
35,
19,
36,
37,
38,
39,
20,
40,
17,
41,
42,
17,
21,
43,
44,
45,
18,
46,
22,
47

I tried to look for this sequence on OEIS but this sequence doesn't exist there which might suggest that a closed form is not easy to find.

Here are the first few $a_n$ where $n$ has the form $\binom{r}{q}$ where $2 \le  q \le r-2$ arranged in the form $(n , a_n)$

(6,6),
(10,7),
(15,8),
(20,9),
(21,9),
(28,10),
(35,10),
(36,11),
(45,12),
(55,13),
(56,11),
(66,14),
(70,12),
(78,15),
(84,12),
(91,16),
(105,17),
(120,13),
(126,13),
(136,19),
(153,20),
(165,14),
(171,21),
(190,22),
(210,14),
(220,15),
(231,24),
(252,15),
(253,25),
(276,26),
(286,16),
(300,27),
(325,28),
(330,15),
(351,29),
(364,17),
(378,30),
(406,31),
(435,32),
(455,18),
(462,16),
(465,33),
(495,16),
(496,34),
(528,35),
(560,19),
(561,36),
(595,37),
(630,38),
(666,39),
(680,20),
(703,40),
(715,17),
(741,41),
(780,42),
(792,17),
(816,21),
(820,43),
(861,44),
(903,45),
(924,18),
(946,46),
(969,22),
(990,47)


Define $s_1=6$, $s_{N+1}$ to be the least integer greater than $s_N$ such that $s_{N+1}$ have the form $\binom{r}{q}$ where $2 \le  q \le r-2$
Here are some graphs of $(n, a_{s_n})$:





$n=\binom{m}{k}$ means $p|n$ for all $\max{ k, m-k} \le p \le m$, but also $n$ has no prime factors larger than $m$. Hence if $n=\binom{m}{k}=\binom{m'}{k'}$ with $m<m'$ there can't be any primes $\max{m,m'-k',k'}<p \le m'$ . So we can't have that many options.

@ZoeAllen Is the $p$ in your first sentence supposed to be a prime? Or just any divisor of n in that range?

This is the pairwise sum of sequences https://oeis.org/A022911 and https://oeis.org/A022912 (with modifications if there are duplicates...)

@nocomment $p$ is prime

@ZoeAllen Ok. Though you're off by 1, for example 21=7C2 isn't divisible by 5.

@nocomment oops you are correct
